# I have overrided EstimateByExtendedAddress it is working new address and guest user. But it is not working customer saved address

Tags: magento2, checkout

```
    public function afterEstimateByExtendedAddress(
        \Magento\Quote\Api\ShipmentEstimationInterface $subject,
        $result,
        $cartId,
        \Magento\Quote\Api\Data\AddressInterface $address
    ) {
        $quote = $this->checkoutSession->getQuote();
        $shippingAddress = $address;


        if (empty($shippingAddress->getCity()))
            return $result;

        $areaTerm = $shippingAddress->getCity() . ':' . $shippingAddress->getCountryId();

        $searchRequest = $this->searchRequestBuilder
            ->setScopeCode('base')
            ->setAreaRadius(80)
            ->setAreaSearchTerm($areaTerm)
            ->create();

        $searchCriteria = $this->searchCriteriaResolver->resolve($searchRequest);

        $searchResult = $this->sourceRepository->getList($searchCriteria);

        $sources = $this->extractor->getSources($searchRequest, $searchResult);
        if (!$sources) {
            throw new NotFoundException(__('Sorry, We can not find available dealer for your address. You may check our pick-in store locations.'));
            $this->logger->info('SearchRequest', $sources);
            return $this->sendPickupOnly($result);
        }
```

Comment: <type name="Magento\Quote\Api\ShipmentEstimationInterface">
        <plugin name="vendor_dropshipping_dealer_delivery" type="Vendor\Dropshipping\Plugin\ShipmentEstimation" />
    </type>   this is the event.xml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `webapi.xml` you can find 2 different methods to estimate

```
<routes>
    <!-- ... -->
    <route url="/V1/carts/mine/estimate-shipping-methods" method="POST">
        <service class="Magento\Quote\Api\ShipmentEstimationInterface" method="estimateByExtendedAddress"/>
        <resources>
            <resource ref="self" />
        </resources>
        <data>
            <parameter name="cartId" force="true">%cart_id%</parameter>
        </data>
    </route>
    <route url="/V1/carts/mine/estimate-shipping-methods-by-address-id" method="POST">
        <service class="Magento\Quote\Api\ShippingMethodManagementInterface" method="estimateByAddressId"/>
        <resources>
            <resource ref="self" />
        </resources>
        <data>
            <parameter name="cartId" force="true">%cart_id%</parameter>
        </data>
    </route>
    <!-- ... -->
</routes>
```

You need to create another one plugin for `Magento\Quote\Api\ShippingMethodManagementInterface::estimateByAddressId`

Comment: It works. Thank you so much